# SharedPreference file is not creating from Fragment

Tags: android-fragments

I am trying to create a SharedPreference from a fragment onCretaeView() method. But not creating.

```
mSharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                                  StockalUtility.PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Any one can tell me where i am doing mistake?

Thanks!